# django regroup with duplicate nametuple

Tags: python, django, templates, alphabetical

I have code for regroup in django template, like below:

```
        {% regroup clients by title.0 as clients_list %}
          {% for client in clients_list %}
            {{ client.grouper }}
              {% for item in client.list %}
                  {% if item.client_link %}
                        <a href="{{ item.client_link }}">{{ item.title }}</a> 
                  {% else %}
                        {{ item.title }}
                  {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

Sometime I have duplicate nametuple in my results for the same letter, for example - 'd':

```
GroupedResult(grouper='d', list=[<Client: decompany_1>]) GroupedResult(grouper='d', list=[<Client: decompany_2>])
```

so in result I have two headers with letter 'd'

Someone know, how to avoid this?

**edit**
views.py

```
class ClientsListView(ListView):
    model = Client
    template_name = 'clients/clients_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'clients'
```

Comment: I assume these groups are not *immediately* after each other? The input should be *ordered* by the grouping condition, since Django regroup works like `groupby` of `itertools`, it looks for "bursts" with the same group.

Comment: So in other words, here your `clients` should be ordered by the `.0` part, although likely in the view you can make do that in the query. Can you share (relevant parts) of the view?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem pls check my edit, in view there is nothing special and maybe this is the reason of failure....

Comment: What if you use `Client.objects.order_by('title')` as `QuerySet`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem with `Client.objects.order_by('title')` - nothing changed